# Syscall - sys/syscall.h - Not such file or directory -

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, system-calls

Where can i find this library?
The compiler reports me: "Not such file or directory"...
I want to call the syscall function included in this library...

Comment: Which OS are you using? Anything in `sys` is platform-dependent; `<sys/syscall.h>` should exist on Linux and maybe some other Unix-like platforms, but not everywhere.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows, but I'm pretty sure it has no equivalent of a Linux syscall. You'll probably need to use the Windows API if you need to interact with the OS. Perhaps you could update the question to show us which syscall you're using, and why, so that someone familiar with Windows can show you what to do instead.

Answer (score 3):

Windows does not have a `<sys/syscall.h>`. If you are trying to port something from Linux to Windows that uses this, then you need something along the lines of:

```
#if __linux
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#include <windows.h>       // Or something like it. 
#endif
```

Of course, most likely your code also won't compile with these changes alone, you will also have to fix up the code that actually uses the declarations in `<sys/syscall.h>`, which will highly depend on exactly what that is.

If you are not quite familiar with porting code and the project is large, I'd check if someone else has made a windows port of the project, because chances are that you will struggle. There are lots of things in a Unix/Linux environment that is quite different from how Windows works.

Comment: whats the difference b/w defined and define where to use defined macro i have only read about define

Comment: `defined` will give a "true" value if the symbol is has been defined before that check. A short form of `#if defined(X)` is `#ifdef X`, which is much more common, but `#ifdef X || Y` won't work, you need `#if defined(X) || defined(Y)`, hence that construction in the `#elif` case.